# Find the value of $\angle x$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, plane-geometry, angle

Question:

[image: img1]

There are no data other than the data in the image

My Approach:

After a lot of time, I was only able to find two isosceles triangles as in the picture.

[image: img2]

Thank you for attending to my question!

Comment: Can you please tell me the source of the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only one hint, rest is straight-forward.

[image]

Apply [Menelaus's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menelaus%27s_theorem) in triangles $ACB,$ $ADB,$ $ACD$ with respect to the traversal $FEH$. This leads you to the fact that $\triangle GDE$ is isosceles.